# How to pass a geolocation lat lng from a function to another's `ll` property in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax, geolocation

I have a Geolocation.js which gets the geolocation and logs it to console. This is imported into an index.js file and need to use those `lat` and `lng` values as logged, to replace the current hard coded values in the `ll` of this:

```
import * as fsAPI from "../data/API_credentials";
import {userGeo} from "../component/Geolocation"

class Helper {
        static baseURL() {
            return "https://api.foursquare.com/v2";
        }
        // Client ID, client secret, and version stored in credentials file
        static auth(){
            const keys = {
                client_id: `${fsAPI.client_id}`,
                client_secret: `${fsAPI.client_secret}`,
                v: `${fsAPI.client_version}`,
                // Trying to get data from {userGeo} 
                // ll: `${userGeo.pos.lat}` + "," + `${userGeo.pos.lng}` //cannot read 'pos' of undefined.
                // Line below works
                ll: "36.04,-86.74"
            }
            return Object.keys(keys).map(key => `${key}=${keys[key]}`)
            .join("&");


        }
```

the code that i import as `userGeo` into the above code is below, in that is my error. How do i refactor this to allow me to grab the `lat lng` in the `ll` above? `userGeo.pos.lat` for example.

You can see my failed attempt above in `` // ll: `${userGeo.pos.lat}` + "," + `${userGeo.pos.lng}` ``, which throw `cannot read 'pos' of undefined.`

```
// Geolocation of user to be used for search query Foursqaure call url

export const userGeo = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
    };

    console.log(pos) // works
    console.log("Lat: " + pos.lat) // works
});
```

thanks a ton!
Ben

Answer (score 1):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous. It accepts a callback as a first argument which will be called after the location will be retrieved. What I would suggest is to promisify and use it inside `auth` function:

```
// Geolocation.js

export const getUserGeo = function (options) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, options);
  });
}

// Helper.js

import { getUserGeo } from "../component/Geolocation";

class Helper {
        static baseURL() {
            return "https://api.foursquare.com/v2";
        }

        static auth(){
            return getUserGeo()
               .then(position => {
                   const keys = {
                      client_id: `${fsAPI.client_id}`,
                      client_secret: `${fsAPI.client_secret}`,
                      v: `${fsAPI.client_version}`,
                      ll: `${position.coords.latitude}` + "," + `${position.coords. longitude}` 
                  };
                  return Object.keys(keys).map(key => `${key}=${keys[key]}`).join("&"); 
               });
}
```

Keep in mind that not `auth()` method is asynchronous which returns a `Promise` which is going to be resolved with the value of `Object.keys(keys).map(key =>`${key}=${keys[key]}`).join("&")`

Comment: i tried this and the `ll` of the API url was `[object%20Promise]`, do you have any suggestions? 

: GET https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?[object%20Promise]&query=juice+coffee&limit=25 400

Comment: Also if i `console.log(position.coords.latitude)` right before the `return Object.keys...` line, it does log the `lat` to the console.

Comment: share the code where you use `auth()` method. seems you are not waiting for a promise returned by `auth()` to resolve

Comment: thank you - i am having trouble pasting it in in code format - i used what you shared initially exactly.

` static auth() {
  return getUserGeo()
   .then(position => {
    const keys = {
     client_id: `${fsAPI.client_id}`,
     client_secret: `${fsAPI.client_secret}`,
     v: `${fsAPI.client_version}`,
     ll: `${position.coords.latitude} + "," + ${position.coords.longitude}`
    };
    console.log(position.coords.latitude)
    return Object.keys(keys).map(key => `${key}=${keys[key]}`).join("&");
   });
 }`

Comment: I am asking about the piece of code where `Helper.auth()` is called

Comment: it is further down in the same file, inside the Helper:
`static simpleFetch(endPoint, method, urlPrams) {`
  `let requestData = {`
   `method,`
   `headers: Helper.headers()`
  `};`
  `return fetch(`${Helper.baseURL()}${endPoint}?${Helper.auth()}&${Helper.urlBuilder(urlPrams)}`,`
   `requestData`
  `).then(res => res.json());`

Comment: Here is the problem - you are not waiting for `Helper.auth()` promise to resolve. You need to wait `Helper.auth()` promise to resolve and only after call `fetch`:
`return Helper.auth().then(authResult => fetch(${Helper.baseURL()}${endPoint}?${authResult}...`.

Comment: that makes sense. i am not totally sure how to implement that... the `fetch` currently lives inside of `static simpleFetch` - do i just move it up into `static auth`'s `.then()`. i tried but wasn't getting it right.